# Recommendations for color palettes

Tags: color

To make my thesis look more consistent I would like to use a single color palette. I want to use it to prepare all drawings, charts etc.

However, I could not find any resources with reasonable proposals. It would be great if you could mention some proposals, or a link to a website that gives some examples.

Comment: This isn't really a TeX and friends question. I'd suggest trying on [typophile](http://typophile.com/).

Comment: I'd agree with @Seamus: implementing a palette in TeX is on topic, but what to use in general is not.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://www.colorcombos.com, http://kuler.adobe.com or http://www.colourlovers.com?